Installing cabinets in an island with uneven depths
I currently have a galley style kitchen. On one of the sides I’m planning on adding a couple cabinets to make an “L” shape.
I purchased a 36 inch blind corner cabinet, but when I align it how I want it there’s about a 2 inch gap between the back of the existing cabinet and the new cabinet. This is part of an island and is exterior facing and can’t just be hidden with counter tops.
Did I buy the wrong cabinet or is there a proper way to solve this?

You're going to need to post a sketch or a photo. I'm not sure I follow your description. Please edit one into your post. Also take the [tour].

I'm not sure why you ordered a blind cabinet for an island. Is the island an L shape?

Blind cabinets are made with the length shorter. They are supposed to be used in a corner, so there would be a wall covering the blind end.  The "blind" section can be moved toward or away from the wall to give the distance needed for drawer clearance based on the pulls ( Handles) planned.
If your intention was to have the cabinet be used for an "L" shaped island, you will need to get an end panel and use some 1x or 2x lumber to make the end of the blind cabinet even with a standard cabinet.

Talked to a installer and this is what they plan to do
